# Creating Project in Gradle

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-custom-view

Hi I am new to gradle build system, but not on Android development itself. I made several libraries and custom layouts that I want to share to community, however I found my self lost on how I can share it. Although I already published some on Github on public, I want to have a gradle link to my project so other devs can use my project through gradle.

for example :

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
```

I want my github project to have some gradle support, I just dont know where to start. Can anyone point me on some guide or tutorials on how to do this. Thank you and happy codings.

Comment: refer this: https://medium.com/@tigr/how-to-publish-your-android-studio-library-to-jcenter-5384172c4739#.f12xokgfu

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: please check above link at first .

Comment: See if this helps: http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html